# How to find a webelement within a webelement or find child element dynamically from parent element (like search element in region)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
Imagine a kanban board UI

to do | inprogress | done
task1   task1       task1
task2   task2       task2
task3   task3       task3
task4   task4       task4
task5   task5       task5

DOM of kanban board:
//--Start--
<iframe id = 'ardafder2312'>
    <div class = 'container'>
        <div class = 'todo'>
            <div class = 'card-title' text='task1'>
            <div class = 'card-title' text='task2'>
            <div class = 'card-title' text='task3'>
            <div class = 'card-title' text='task4'>
            <div class = 'card-title' text='task5'>
        </div>  
        <div class = 'inprogress'>
            <div class = 'card-title' text='task1'>
            <div class = 'card-title' text='task2'>
            <div class = 'card-title' text='task3'>
            <div class = 'card-title' text='task4'>
            <div class = 'card-title' text='task5'>
        </div>  
        <div class = 'done'>
            <div class = 'card-title' text='task1'>
            <div class = 'card-title' text='task2'>
            <div class = 'card-title' text='task3'>
            <div class = 'card-title' text='task4'>
            <div class = 'card-title' text='task5'>
        </div>  
</iframe>

//--End--
```

//Below snippet works

```
switchto(iframe)
WebElement container = driver.findelement(by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'container')]//*[contains(@class,'todo')]//*[text(),'task1']").click());
```

Requirement is to **click on 'task5' under column 'done' using dynamic function** and I'm looking to do it using a concept search in region from Sikuli. Find the parent and search child inside it.

Hence created a function below where we identify a parent webelement and search child webelement inside it.

Please let me know if this works or any changes to be done.

```
function test(String state, String taskName)
{
    WebElement container = driver.findelement(by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'container')]//*[contains(@class,'"+state+"')]")); //trying to create a region - parent
    WebElement task = container.findelement(by_xpath("//*[text(),'task1']"))  //trying to search within the container - child of above parent
}

test("done", "task1")
```

**Result:**

**Expected Result: User is supposed to click on 'task1' available under 'done' column**

**Actual Result (ISSUE): click is happening on 'task1' available under 'todo' column.**

Comment: try using index of the `task5` use xpath= (.//div[@class='done']/div)[5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`WebElement task = container.findelement(by_xpath("//*[text(),'task1']"))`

to

`WebElement task = container.findelement(by_xpath(".//*[text(),'task1']"))`

`.` would mean that you start from current node